# Fetching and checkout a remote branch without detached head

Tags: git

I fetch a remote branch via `git fetch origin name-of-branch:refs/remotes/name-of-branch`.

I use `git checkout name-of-branch` I am put in a detached head state.  I can get to a named branch now by using `git checkout -b some-branch-name`.  Is there any way to checkout the remote branch to a named branch (of the same name even) in one command?

If I use `git checkout -b name-of-remote-branch` (i.e. use the same name), then checkout another branch, then check that branch out again `git checkout name-of-remote-branch`, I get

```
warning: refname 'name-of-remote-branch' is ambiguous.
```

However, this doesn't happen if I use `git pull` first and then use checkout:

```
Branch name-of-pulled-branch set up to track remote branch name-of-pulled-branch from origin
```

I assume that a lot of my woes with respect to the fetched branch have to do with the fact that it is *not* set up to track the remote branch.  Why is this, and is there any way to checkout the fetched branched and have it set up to track the remote branch as if I had used `git pull`?

Comment: The "normal" form for a remote branch is `refs/remotes/origin/name-of-branch` (assuming a remote named `origin`), *not* the version *without* the remote-name.  When you spell out the second version, it makes git's "do what I mean" algorithms go slightly awry.  When you use `git pull` you're not supplying a "weird" form of remote branch name.

Comment: @torek you mean as opposed to `name-of-branch:refs/...`?

Comment: Extra arguments to `fetch` are "refspecs", so, "mostly yes" :) .  It's just that in `x:y` the `x` part is the local name and the `y` part is the remote name, and I was only typing in the remote name.  (I normally just run `git fetch -p <remote>` or equivalent and let all new remote branches spring up as needed.)  See also the long description in the man page, the `:y` part is handled a bit oddly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
git fetch origin name-of-branch:refs/remotes/name-of-branch
git checkout -b some-branch-name name-of-remote-branch --track
```

This will set up tracking so that git pull/push will Just Work.

Comment: Why isn't it necessary to do the `-b` and `--track` if I pulled the remote branch but did not fetch it?

Comment: Git pull can be thought of as a superset of git fetch - From the man page: "(Git pull) Runs git fetch with the given parameters, and calls git merge to merge the retrieved head(s) into the current branch." It does also set up tracking for you.

Comment: So is there any way to set up tracking without checking out the branch?  When you use `git pull` and then `git checkout` *that*'s when it does the "Branch set to track..."  This implies to me that you can fetch a remote branch and then set it up for tracking before checking it out as if you had pulled it.

Comment: So fetching does not create a local branch at all. Fetching pulls all the 'data' for a remote - and its branches will be available as remote-name/branch-name. It is when you check out a remote branch as a local branch that you want the tracking to be setup. I *think* then when you git pull a remote directly for the first time, it fetches, merges with the branch you asked it to, and sets up tracking to make future 'git pull's work - but I never really use git pull this way. My workflow has been git fetch remote; git checkout -b local remote/somebranch --track; (and subsequently) git pull

Comment: To better answer "So is there any way to set up tracking without checking out the branch?" - What does this mean - tracking *is* a local branch tracking a remote branch. If you don't have a local branch, what will track what? :)

Comment: I understand that, but what I am saying is that when you do `git checkout` after `git pull` you don't have to do anything like `--track`.  What does `git pull` do to allow you to skip that step?

Comment: git pull sets up tracking for the *current* branch. What you checkout later is not related to the current branch. Could you maybe show your exact sequence of commands, say, with dummy branch and remote names for the two cases you're comparing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45478/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-stellarhopper)

Comment: The steps I use are all in the question (I'm not trying to be snarky).  Essentially if I use `git pull` and then `git checkout some-branch-i-didnt-have-before-pull` it sets up the tracking *at that point* with the "Branch set to track..." message.  If I do the exact same thing with `git fetch` (fetch a ref, then use `git checkout`) I get the detached head and it's *not* set to track.  So it seems like it's set to track at checkout time.  Must be a difference in the ref acquired by `git pull` vs. `git fetch` ... but what is that difference?